# Using libstdc++ compiled libraries with clang++ -stdlib=libc++

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libstdc++, libc++

I am working in C++ under Mac OS X (10.8.2) and I recently came up with the need of using C++11 features, which are available through the clang++ compiler using the libc++ stdlib.
However, I also need to use some legacy library compiled and linked against libstdc++ (coming from MacPorts).

In doing so, I got linking errors, since the headers of the legacy libraries using, e.g., `std::string`, required to be resolved against the `std::__1::basic_string` (i.e., the libc++ implementation of `std::string`) instead of the `std::basic_string` implementation.

Is there a way to mix the two libraries in development (e.g. by using some preprocessors flags?)

Answer (score 98):

What you're seeing is the use of *inline namespaces* to achieve ABI versioning.

**What that means:**

The libstdc++ `std::string` is a different data structure than the libc++ `std::string`.  The former is a reference counted design, whereas the latter is not.  Although they are API compatible, they are not ABI compatible.  That means that if you construct a `std::string` with libstdc++, and then pass it to other code that is linked against libc++, the receiving code would think it has a libc++ `std::string`.  I.e. the receiver would not have a clue that it should be incrementing or decrementing reference counts.

Without inline namespaces, the result would be a run time error.  The best you could hope for is a crash.  With inline namespaces this run time error is translated into a link time error.

To you the programmer the libstdc++ `std::string` and the libc++ `std::string` look like the same type.  But to the linker, they look like completely different types (the clue is the `std::__1` namespace).  And the linker's view is correct.  They **are** completely different types.

So yes, you could manipulate some preprocessor flags to get things to link.  But then you would have a devil of a time debugging the resultant run time bugs.

The only way to do what you want to is to make the interfaces between these dylibs not involve `std::` types such as `string`.  For example you could pass arrays of `char` instead.  You can even transfer memory ownership from libstdc++-linked code to libc++-linked code and vice-versa (they will both drop through to the same malloc pool).

Comment: So, summarizing, there's no hope to use legacy libraries (i.e., libraries linked against libstdc++) with libc++. That's really a serious limitation

Comment: There is a maximum hope:  You can mix the two libraries in a process as long as you don't pass versioned symbols across dylib boundaries.  And if you accidentally do, the mistake is caught at link time.  You can throw `std::exception`-derived exceptions across dylib boundaries and transfer memory ownership across dylib boundaries.  I suspect this may be better ABI compatibility than gcc will provide with its own 4.2 version.  Note that by the std spec, not even `std::string` is ABI compatible between C++98/03 and C++11.  The former is widely ref-counted whereas the latter is forbidden to be.

Comment: Another example:  The pre-C++11 gcc `std::list` is not ABI compatible with the C++11 spec of `std::list`.  In other words:  your remark about libc++ applies equally well (if not more) to pre-C++11 versions of libstdc++.  libc++ is no more ABI incompatible with pre-C++11 libstdc++ than a C++11-conforming libstdc++ will be.

Comment: Actually, if one of the two libraries is boost something, you have little hope to get rid of `std::string` :-(

Comment: @user1690715 It would be more accurate to say that there's no hope for interworking libraries build against the two runtimes when they expose STL objects on their APIs - something which has always been a very dicey proposition.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to create an assignment overload for std::string to std::_1::string and vice-versa ?

Comment: @michael Neat idea. It would be a bit compilcated. It seems you would have to be able to #include the headers from both versions of the stdlibs for that to work, and have them in the correct namespace right at compile time.