# Link iOS app against both libstdc++ and libc++

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, c++11, linker

Use case: I want to use a 3rd party static library that uses libstdc++ (cannot be changed), so I have to link my app against libstdc++. Now if I want to use C++11 features in my own code, I'd have to select libc++ in Xcode and additionally link against libstdc++ to satisfy the static library.

My problem is that even though I selected libc++ in "Build settings" and added "-lstdc++" to "Other linker flags" (also tried via "Build phases > Link Binary With Libraries"), I'm getting linker errors for the latter, that is for libstdc++ functions/classes referenced by the 3rd party lib.

How can I configure the project to link against both C++ standard libraries? It should theoretically be possible since libc++ will be in its own inline namespace `std::__1`.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12546314/1921751)? It may give you a hint on how to solve your problem. Personally, I think it will be a real pain to get that working with both libstdc++ and libc++, but anything is possible! Isn't there any way you can get the source from those 3rd party static libraries and compile them using libc++? I had this problem but fortunately I had access to the source so I just recompiled everything with "-stdlib=libc++" and the linker errors were gone.

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into this , and my solution was that instead of adding `-lstdc++` on the other flags, that you put `/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib`.

My hunch is that when xcode/clang has `-std=c++` set, the older .dylib needs to be explicitly loaded.