# How to solve UnitTest++ linker errors using C++11 and CMake on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, c++11, linker, cmake, unittest++

I am trying to compile tests for a library which uses C++11 using CMake. I have had success using UnitTest++ with C++11 on Ubuntu, however Mac OS X is giving me linker errors.

In CMake my linker flags and libraries for APPLE look like this:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--stdlib=libc++ --std=c++11")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mytest unittest++)
```

Compiling with this gives me linker errors such as:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      UnitTest::MemoryOutStream::GetText() const in libunittest++.a(MemoryOutStream.o)
  "std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const", referenced from:
      UnitTest::MemoryOutStream::GetText() const in libunittest++.a(MemoryOutStream.o)
  "std::ostream::~std::ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::ostream-in-UnitTest::MemoryOutStream in libunittest++.a(TestRunner.o)
      construction vtable for std::ostream-in-UnitTest::MemoryOutStream in libunittest++.a(Test.o)
....
```

Here is the [full paste](http://pastebin.com/FYnvhPYa).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11")`?

Comment: That doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your copy of `libunittest++.a` was compiled with a different implementation of the standard C++ library. On OS X there are now two implementations of the standard C++ library: GNU's libstdc++, whose header files reside in `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` and Clang's libc++, whose header files are in `/usr/lib/c++/v1/`.

Your copy of `libunittest++.a` appears to have been compiled with GNU's libstdc++, so you can either fix the issue by using the same library for your program:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++11")
```

Or re-compile `libunittest++.a` with using Clang's libc++.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542971/using-libstdc-compiled-libraries-with-clang-stdlib-libc) for more helpful information.