# Does boost use C++11 "inline namespaces" to avoid ABI incompatibilty errors at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, inline-namespaces

C++11 has a feature called "inline namespaces", which allows authors to enforce ABI compatibility at *link time* without tampering with the API.  For instance, these helpful answers from @HowardHinnant explain how `libc++` uses inline namespaces:

- [Using libstdc++ compiled libraries with clang++ -stdlib=libc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542971/using-libstdc-compiled-libraries-with-clang-stdlib-libc)
- [Why can't clang with libc++ in c++0x mode link this boost::program_options example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454329/why-cant-clang-with-libc-in-c0x-mode-link-this-boostprogram-options-examp)

My question is: Does boost make use of this C++11 feature?  It looks like some boost devs were at least [thinking](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Idea-for-discussion-Putting-version-number-in-boost-namespace-td2644010.html) of eventually using it at one point.  But that thread is pretty old.  Did it ever happen?  If so, does apply to all boost libraries, or only a subset?

Comment: `grep "inline namespace"` might be useful here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some libraries have started to use it, but not all. For example this is in Boost.Log:

```
//! NOTE: I've reformatted this to look cleaner.
#if !defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_INLINE_NAMESPACES)
    inline namespace BOOST_LOG_VERSION_NAMESPACE {}
    [snip]
#endif
```