# Clang does not recognize std::shared_ptr with libstdc++

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

I have this snippet:

```
#include <memory>
int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int);
}
```

If I compile with `clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libstdc++ main.cpp` I get this error:

```
main.cpp:4:8: error: no member named 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std'
  std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int);
  ~~~~~^
```

It works well when using `stdlib=libc++` instead. The version of the libstdc++ is 6.0.9 and the compiler is

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

I see the same result when using `clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final)`.

I have realized that it works if I use `tr1`, but this seems less portable to me:

```
#include <tr1/memory>
int main() {
  std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> p(new int);
}
```

So, isn't it possible to use `std::shared_ptr` with clang and libstdc++?

Comment: That depends on your version of GCC/libstdc++. It is likely you're on a platform that ships a very old version of GCC.

Comment: As I guessed, libstdc++ 6.0.9 ships with GCC 4.2.1. You should consider updating GCC (i.e, via homebrew.) I think that you have to recompile clang using `--with-gcc-toolchain` pointing to your GCC 4.8 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac ships a very old version of GCC (4.2.1) which of course comes with a very old libstdc++. The [Getting Started](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) page for LLVM says:

> If you intend to use Clang's C++ support, you may need to tell it how
>   to find your C++ standard library headers. In general, Clang will
>   detect the best version of libstdc++ headers available and use them -
>   it will look both for system installations of libstdc++ as well as
>   installations adjacent to Clang itself. If your configuration fits
>   neither of these scenarios, you can use the `--with-gcc-toolchain`
>   configure option to tell Clang where the gcc containing the desired
>   libstdc++ is installed.

This would be the easiest way to do it, simply point it to where your modern GCC installation is. If you don't want to recompile Clang, then you can try to follow the instructions from this [mailing list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-April/021052.html):

> Yes, of course. Finding the standard library is no magic, you can
>   simply  add some -isystem, -L, and possibly -Wl,-rpath arguments to
>   clang++ when  using it. Use the -v option to see what clang is using
>   by default, so you  can just add the same with s/4.4/4.7/g. If clang
>   puts one of its own  directories first (before the gcc ones), be sure
>   to specify it again  yourself so it still ends up first. You can even
>   try some flags like 
>   -nostdinc++ to clean up a bit (again, check with -v that the list makes  sense).
>
> --  Marc Glisse

Keep in mind that if you manage to get clang++ working with a newer libstdc++, that libstdc++ and libc++ are [binary incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542971/using-libstdc-compiled-libraries-with-clang-stdlib-libc). That means that any libraries (such as Boost) that were compiled with one must be recompiled with the other.