# OpenCV symbols are undefined using gcc 5.1

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, gcc

I have a very basic program to test that OpenCV works.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::namedWindow("Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cv::VideoCapture video_capture;
    video_capture.open(0);

    while (true) {
        cv::Mat image;
        video_capture.read(image);

        cv::imshow("Window", image);

        if (cv::waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And a CMakeLists.txt file that finds OpenCV like so:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries(Project ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

This works on Mac OSX 10.10 using OpenCV 2.4.10 and clang 602.0.49, but If I try to use gcc 5.1 by putting `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/gcc-5.1.0/bin/g++-5.1.0)` in my CMakeLists.txt, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::namedWindow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: It might be the [new ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#libstdcxx).

Comment: I want to use C++ 11 though.

Comment: So? Have you read what they wrote about the new ABI and how to fix problems in case linking fails for symbols including `std::__cxx11::`?

Comment: @DanielFrey so I just have to recompile opencv using gcc 5.1?

Comment: No. Just add `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0` before including any other headers.

Comment: @DanielFrey I was assuming a recompile was needed. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12546314/1180117) suggests use of preprocessor will create runtime issue. Is that different from this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Please recompile your OpenCV using the same version of gcc that you use to compile the above code. This problem should hopefully disappear. From the official gcc pages,

> If you get linker errors about undefined references to symbols that involve types in the std::__cxx11 namespace or the tag [abi:cxx11] then it probably indicates that you are trying to link together object files that were compiled with different values for the _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI macro. This commonly happens when linking to a third-party library that was compiled with an older version of GCC. If the third-party library cannot be rebuilt with the new ABI then you will need to recompile your code with the old ABI.

Comment: With versions of gcc before 6, this can be accomplished by calling cmake with CXXFLAGS set to "-std=c++11" or "-std=c++14": `CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11" cmake ..`

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem testing in a CentOS 7.9 container with gcc 5.3.1. We tried many solutions as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004976/undefined-reference-to-processstd-cxx11basic-string-when-compiling-a), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500337/how-to-handle-dual-abi-in-gcc-5), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring), and although none worked as-is, the associated discussion and comments -- especially about using linker verbosity ('-Wl,--verbose') to understand what it's trying to do -- contributed pieces of the puzzle. After a day of struggle we solved it by downloading a later version of libstdc++ (6.0.21 vs 6.0.19) to /usr/lib64 and breaking the libstdc++.so symlink to point at the newer version. This allowed older OpenCV libs to link and -- so far -- has not broken anything else.

Note that we *only* changed the libstdc++ .so -- downloading various rpms, trying to upgrade the container, adding -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 build flag, etc - none of those worked.

We found it odd the issue didn't occur in our testing with gcc4 and gcc6-9 -- only with gcc5. As far as I can tell, after gcc 5 was released in 2015 time-frame, it wasn't long before this issue had significant attention, and updated versions of libstdc++ came along soon after.