# Ubuntu undefined reference error

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gcc4, gcc5

I'm trying to compile a program written on C++. I got this message error:

```
undefined reference to `escapeXMLChars(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
```

I've searched and found this post: [Undefined reference to process(std::__cxx11::basic_string ... ) when compiling affdex linux sample applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004976/undefined-reference-to-processstd-cxx11basic-string-when-compiling-a)

I assumed this error happened because I used GCC version 5. So I tried to downgrade it to 4.8 and compiled the program with gcc-4.8. But I still got this error, this is the output:

```
g++-4.8 -m32 -Wall -o boomerang driver.o codegen/chllcode.o codegen/syntax.o util/util.o db/basicblock.o db/proc.o db/sslscanner.o db/cfg.o db/prog.o db/table.o db/statement.o db/register.o db/sslparser.o db/exp.o db/rtl.o db/sslinst.o db/insnameelem.o db/signature.o db/managed.o c/ansi-c-parser.o c/ansi-c-scanner.o boomerang.o log.o db/visitor.o db/dataflow.o db/xmlprogparser.o  frontend/frontend.o frontend/njmcDecoder.o frontend/sparcdecoder.o frontend/pentiumdecoder.o frontend/sparcfrontend.o frontend/pentiumfrontend.o frontend/ppcdecoder.o frontend/ppcfrontend.o frontend/st20decoder.o frontend/st20frontend.o frontend/mipsdecoder.o frontend/mipsfrontend.o frontend/_8051frontend.o frontend/_8051decoder.o type/constraint.o type/type.o type/dfa.o loader/BinaryFileFactory.o transform/rdi.o transform/transformer.o transform/generic.o transform/transformation-parser.o transform/transformation-scanner.o db/AssHandler.o db/AssScanner.o    -Wl,-rpath -Wl,"lib" -lfl -Llib -lgc -ldl -m32 -lBinaryFile -lexpat
db/proc.o: In function `UserProc::printDecodedXML()':
proc.cpp:(.text+0x4590): undefined reference to `escapeXMLChars(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
```

I don't know why, should I downgrade gcc to older version?

Comment: Try the `-std=c++11` flag to gcc.

Comment: Where this function comes from? Is it's library and path to it included in your list of linked libraries?

Comment: @MattSchuchard: I'm using a configure command like this: ./configure --host=i686-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32". How do I add -std flag to this command?

Comment: @Ternvein: It's a function in other file, not a library function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem and finally compiled successful the program. Adjust my configure to:

./configure --host=i686-linux-gnu "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32" "CC=gcc -std=c++11 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" "CXX=g++ -std=c++11 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"