# make error) Undefined reference to std::__cxx11::basic_string

Tags: makefile, undefined-reference, binutils

When I command `make`, I got errors like this:

```
filter_block.cc:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)'
```

I found some solutions for this error, like adding `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, but I don't know how to add the command for `make` command.

The `Makefile` is written as:

```
.SUFFIXES: .c .cpp
CC              = g++ -fopenmp
CFLAGS          = -c -O2 -Wall -D_I386 -D_UNIX -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare
LFLAGS          = -shared -O2 -o
LIBS            = -llmi -lblas -lboost_regex -lpthread -lleveldb
```

How can I add `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` into `Makefile`?

*Ubuntu version = 14.04

*libstdc++ version

```
$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++
libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

*gcc version

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) 5.4.1 20160904
```

*ld version

```
$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
```

Comment: Try to add -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 to the end of the line of CFLAGS          =

Comment: I add `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to the end of the line of `CFLAGS`, but it doesn't work well. There's same error when I compile

Comment: @gi-yeon-shin then probably the problem is not in the Makefile? Please compile the program using only gcc. 
Also try to use another version of gcc (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004976/undefined-reference-to-processstd-cxx11basic-string-when-compiling-a). I think you should localize the problem and make another post with some of your source code.

Comment: Looks similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776046/compiling-error-with-make-command-std-cxx11
is libleveldb compiled with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`  too?

Comment: I don't know whether libleveldb is compiled with `D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, because the file is made by other

Comment: But his code works well in his environment, I don't know why the code doesn't work in my environment

Comment: I made another post with the source code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776046/compiling-error-with-make-command-std-cxx11?noredirect=1#comment92484003_52776046)