# Link errors when compiling OpenCV code with cuda CXX compiler

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, abi

I installed opencv on my machine using pacman (running Arch Linux), and I am now trying to compile a [simple openCV program](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html).

If I compile my code using the default compiler on my machine (GNU 9.2.0), everything works just fine. If I use `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/cuda/bin/g++` (GNU 8.3.0), then I get a bunch of link errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.1.2: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.26'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libopencv_gapi.so.4.1.2: undefined reference to `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::logic_error&&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.26'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libopencv_gapi.so.4.1.2: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.26'
```

Looking at [similar questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064618/opencv-symbols-are-undefined-using-gcc-5-1), this is likely caused by conflicting versions of the standard library. However, the cuda version of g++ really isn't that old, so I am a bit confused. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html